# showing dynamic data from database in all views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-2.0

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have a Model within my `notes` application

**notes/models.py**

```
class ColorLabels(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
```

In the sidebar navigation which will be displayed on all pages, I want to show the list of color labels and it will show on all pages.

**How can I show dynamic data in all views or say on all pages?**

Comment: Use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: it worked.Thanks. You can make it an answer so that I could mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [custom template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

This will add the context (data) you need into the templates rendered by all views.

---

First create the context processor (**`notes/context_processors.py`**):

```
from .models import ColorLabel

def color_labels(request):
    return {'color_labels': ColorLabel.objects.all()}
```

Then add it to the [`context_processors` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) of your template renderer in **`settings.py`**:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': '...',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'notes.context_processors.color_labels',
            ...
        ],
    },
}]
```

Finally, you will be able to use it in your templates:

**`templates/base.html`**

```
<nav>
    {% for color_label in color_labels %}
        {{ color_label.title }}
    {% endfor %}
</nav>
```